# How do you delete a retweet in Tweetdeck web version?

Tags: delete, retweet, tweetdeck

I found the answer about how to delete a tweet you've posted but not how to delete a retweet in Tweetdeck web version.

Answer (score 4):

Use "Undo Retweet" item at the very bottom of the context menu displayed when you click on the three dots at the bottom right of a tweet:

[image: shot]

(Perhaps counterintuitively, clicking the green "retweeted" button does not offer an option to undo the retweet).

Answer (score 0):

Click the three dots then click delete.